# R package for the new IpadOS 2020

Tags: ios, r, ipad, ipados

I´m trying to install R in my new Ipad but i can´t find a package that completely fits on it and can replace my old laptop. Can anyone tell me if its possible to code in R in IpadOS? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find this app:
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/r-programming-compiler/id1158038782

Write R code directly on your iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch! This app is ideal for learning and testing code snippets!

Answer (score 0):

Apple has just approved ish, a free X86 mode emulator running Alpine Linux. The wiki (https://github.com/ish-app/ish/wiki) has instructions for installing R, as well as comments on adding compiled packages. I just started with it, and haven’t figured out how to get an active graphics device. I can generate pdf files, though.